# Horizontally align text inside a DIV container

Tags: html, css

I have a structure like:

```
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="left-wrapper">
            Lorem Ipsum... <!-- This is what I want horizontally aligned -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my CSS file is like:

```
.content-wrapper {
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-wrapper left-wrapper {
    min-height: inherit;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

What I want to do is: doesn't matter how big my text inside the `left-wrapper` is, I want a `padding-top` and a `padding-bottom` equal to `30px`, for example, and my text perfectly aligned horizontally.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `text-align:center;` ?

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: text-align:justify; ?

Comment: @Isotope he is asking for horizontal align

Comment: i think left align you can float it (float: left;)

Comment: if you align something on the horizon, then it's in the middle vertically. Either way, we've got him sorted between us

Comment: you want horizontal center (or) vertical center???

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
.content-wrapper .left-wrapper {
    min-height: inherit;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    padding:30px 0;
}
```

Here's a [JSBIN.](http://jsbin.com/reguneyutogu/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
.content-wrapper .left-wrapper {
    min-height: inherit;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/0dfxv8tw/

Answer (score 0):

In your code replace

```
.content-wrapper left-wrapper {
```

with

```
.content-wrapper .left-wrapper {
```

and provide

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<div class="div01">
<div class="div02">
    <div class="div03">
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; font-size:12px; color:#333; font-family:Arial;}
.div01 {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.div02{
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:table;
}
.div03 {
vertical-align:middle;
height:100%;
display:table-cell;
border:1px solid #000;
line-height:22px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/5qb9ke1q/)